# Which Icon Editing Software would you recommend for creating icons for apps

Tags: graphics, icons

I once bought a single license of [Microangelo](http://www.microangelo.us/) for creating icons which served me well in the past, but now I'm helping run up a new Virtual Machine base for our dev team to use and would like to include a **decent free icon editor** in there.

I'd prefer something that fully supports creating icons for Windows Vista.

For all those of you thinking "Don't let a developer design graphics!" just pretend I said "for our UI Design Team" instead of "Dev Team", lol. ;)

Answer (score 6):

That's simple, because it's free, powerfull and supports Vista Icons (256x256): [IcoFx](http://www.icofx.ro)

On this site you can find a tool for (animated) cursors, too: [AniFx](http://www.icofx.ro/anifx/index.html)

If you want to pay, I'd suggest a more powerful ones: [Axialis Iconworkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/)

Answer (score 6):

I would use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) to design the icons, and then render them scaled down and convert them  to the final format with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

The benefit of this is you can design the icon once, and produce it in many target sizes effortlessly.

That's what the OpenSource world are doing these days :)  ( We even have Native SVG Icons now )

Comment: I do the design with Inkscape, too, but than save it to .ico with IcoFx, because it can generate icon libraries with different resolutions and color depths.

Comment: So can GIMP, it's just the interface isn't very good. Drag each transparent PNG into a separate layer on the layer list. The main bitmap display will look like rubbish, but save as ICO and it'll work fine.

Comment: I use Inkscape as well. However, I have a separate file for each icon size, since I optimize the icon (detail, line widths, etc.) for each size.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Paint.NET](http://www.paint.net), or [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org).  They're not specifically for icons, but will do the job and much more.  Also, both free.

EDIT: Paint.NET requires [plugin](http://www.evanolds.com/pdnicocur.html) (free).

Comment: Are you sure Paint.NET will do the job - I didn't think you could save to .ico in it? Yeah, I tried using The Gimp a couple years ago but felt the UI was very unintuiative (imho), maybe I should give it another look. Does it allow saving to .ico?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I installed it a while back and forgot about the plug in.  As for The GIMP, the tutorial for creating icons can be found at: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Creating_Icons/

Answer (score 1):

For icons, there's [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/).