# Easiest way to use Vista icons in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, icons

I've downloaded a Vista icon from the web for a new application I'm developing. When I try to compile it in Visual Studio 2005 C++, I get an error message:

> error RC2176 : old DIB in res\XXXXX.ico; pass it through SDKPAINT

The error message seems a little misleading, I think the "old DIB" is actually a newer format that it wasn't expecting.  I've never heard of SDKPAINT, and Search doesn't find it installed on my system anywhere. Microsoft claims SDKPAINT comes with the Windows 3.0 SDK, but I can't download any SDK due to incompatibilities with our firewall.

I don't really need anything Vista specific in this icon, so anything that would dump the incompatible bits would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more digging, and I found this previous question:

[Which Icon Editing Software would you recommend for creating icons for apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468195/which-icon-editing-software-would-you-recommend-for-creating-icons-for-apps)

The accepted answer for that question suggested [IcoFX](http://www.icofx.ro/). I downloaded that and used it to delete the 256x256 and 128x128 versions of the icon, and now everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more ways to achieve this in Visual Studio 2005:

- replace `rc.exe` and `rcdll.exe` of your Visual Studio 2005 installation with the ones from a newer SDK (e.g. Windows Vista, 7 ...) or DDK/WDK (ditto)
- or integrate the newer SDK into your Visual Studio 2005 using the respective tool that comes with the SDK

The resource compiler is the part that creates the `.res` files and then the usual Visual Studio 2005 linker (with the first option) or the SDK tool chain's liner links that into the binary. Meaning that even in conservative scenarios where it is frowned upon to upgrade the tool chain as a whole, this should be harmless.